# Get multiple solutions in SWI-Prolog using toplevel

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm beginner in SWI-Prolog (but have some experience in Borland Prolog), and I've faced with a strange behavior for the following test code:

```
test(10).
test(1).
```

It is expected for query `?-test(A)` to get 2 solutions, something like `A = 10; A = 1`. However, only `A = 10` is produced. I don't use the cut here. Maybe backtracking is off by default in SWI-Prolog?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when `A=10` returned pres `;` to get another solutions and so on...

Comment: Coder, many thanks for reply, and sorry for stupid question. I didn't expect that it is necessary to press Spacebar or semicolon after each solution, and I pressed Return.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, the answer is very simple (see [SWI-Prolog doc](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/quickstart.html)):

> The user can type the semi-colon (;) or spacebar, if (s)he wants another solution. Use the return key if you do not want to see the more answers. Prolog completes the output with a full stop (.) if the user uses the return key or Prolog knows there are no more answers. If Prolog cannot find (more) answers, it writes false.

Comment: The manual is a great source of information for how the basic aspects of SWI Prolog works.

Comment: When should you "type the semi-colon"? After entering a query like `?-pred(X).` I must press enter to get the solution, which also brings me to a new line where I can only enter after `?-` as if another query.

Comment: user289661, type semicolon after getting solution, f you want to get other solutions. If you don't need more solutions, press enter.

Answer (score 3):

[bagof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3) is probably what you're looking for.

```
?- bagof(X, test(X), Xs).
```

where `Xs` is a list of all matching results. 
Know that anonymous variables don't work how you might expect with bagof. In the following example:

```
test(1,odd).
test(2,even).
test(3,odd).
test(4,even).
```

`bagof(X, test(X,_), Xs)` will only give values of X where the second term is uniform; in this case only the even numbers. If you want to return all matching value you need to do something like

```
?- bagof(X, A^test(X,A), Xs).
```

Comment: Jordan C.M., thanks for reply. There is also `findall`, thanks. I sought a way to see multiple solution from console, but your info is useful, thansk again.